# ¿Cómo debería de asignarle el Type a Location?: Error al usar location en React + Typescript con react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

**MENSAJE DE ERROR**
Type '{ location: Location; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, UnknownFacade>, never>, any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.
Property 'location' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, UnknownFacade>, never>, any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.

```
Type '{ location: Location<UnknownFacade>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, UnknownFacade>, never>, any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.
  Property 'location' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, UnknownFacade>, never>, any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.  TS2322

     8 |     <Router>
     9 |         <Switch>
  > 10 |             <Route exact path='/' render={({location}) => <Visited location={location} />}/>
       |                                                                    ^
    11 |             <Route path='/admin' component={Admin} />
    12 |         </Switch>
    13 |     </Router>
```

**COMPORTAMIENTO ESPERADO**
Que me compile sin tener que poner el tipo "any" a location

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {HashRouter as Router, Route ,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Visited from '../modules/visited';
import Admin from '../modules/admin';


const App: React.FC = () => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' render={({location}) => <Visited location={location} />}/>
            <Route path='/admin' component={Admin} />            
        </Switch>
    </Router>
)

export default App;
```

**Visited.tsx**

```
import React  from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './containers/home';


const Visited: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = ({location}) => {
    return (
        <Switch location={location} key={location.pathname}>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Visited);
```

Comment: De donde viene `location` en tu componente *App*?

Comment: en el metodo render de un Route en react-router te vienen las props y una de esas props es ese location que solamente lo estoy destructurando en mi componente App y que ese mismo estoy queriendo pasar al componente Visited - tal vez formule mal la pregunta - seria algo asi **Que tipo(typescript) recibe el Location** ya que si lo pongo como any - todo me funciona bien

Answer (score 0):

## SOLUCION - RESUELTA

react-router tenia problemas con el RouteComponentsProps al usar typescript, por eso opte por usar la libreria de @reach/router - y con este me funciono perfectamente.!

**App.tsx**

[image: App.tsx]

**Visited.tsx**

[image: Visited.tsx]